# Why does my twitter bot post more than expected?

Tags: python, twitter

I am using the code `time.sleep(3600)` and it is tweeting more than every 3600 seconds. Why is this happening?

Currently it is tweeting at 9 minutes past, then 32 minutes past.

Edit:

Here is the code. The only other reason this could be happening is that this may be running in multiple instances accidentally. I will check that.

```
# tweepy will allow us to communicate with Twitter, time will allow us to set how often we tweet
import tweepy, time

#enter the corresponding information from your Twitter application management:
CONSUMER_KEY = 'mykey' #keep the quotes, replace this with your consumer key
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'mykey' #keep the quotes, replace this with your consumer secret key
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'my-my' #keep the quotes, replace this with your access token
ACCESS_SECRET = 'mykey' #keep the quotes, replace this with your access token secret


# configure our access information for reaching Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)

# access Twitter!
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# open our content file and read each line
filename=open('content.txt')
f=filename.readlines()
filename.close()

# for each line in our contents file, lets tweet that line out except when we hit a error
for line in f:
    try:
        api.update_status(line)
        print("Tweeting!")
    except tweepy.TweepError as err:
        print(err)
    time.sleep(3600) #Tweet every hour
print("All done tweeting!")
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by your module not being protected from running when imported.
That means every time your module is imported, (could happen on

```
from package import *
```

), your code is interpreted and a new loop is created.

---

You could ensure your code is run only when you want it to run with this :

Make a function from your code, let's name it main().

You can then check if your module is called as a script.

```
def main():
    # tweepy will allow us to communicate with Twitter, time will allow us to set how often we tweet
    import tweepy, time

    #enter the corresponding information from your Twitter application management:
    CONSUMER_KEY = 'mykey' #keep the quotes, replace this with your consumer key
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'mykey' #keep the quotes, replace this with your consumer secret key
    ACCESS_TOKEN = 'my-my' #keep the quotes, replace this with your access token
    ACCESS_SECRET = 'mykey' #keep the quotes, replace this with your access token secret


    # configure our access information for reaching Twitter
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)

    # access Twitter!
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    # open our content file and read each line
    filename=open('content.txt')
    f=filename.readlines()
    filename.close()

    # for each line in our contents file, lets tweet that line out except when we hit a error
    for line in f:
        try:
            api.update_status(line)
            print("Tweeting!")
        except tweepy.TweepError as err:
            print(err)
        time.sleep(3600) #Tweet every hour
    print("All done tweeting!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

If you have to use your code from another script, you can use

```
from your_module import main
main()
```

Or from a command line :

```
python -m your_module
```